# Monkey patching a Django form class?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, monkeypatching

Given a form class (somewhere deep in your giant Django app)..

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = ...
    surname = ...
```

And considering you want to add another field to this form without **extending or modifying the form class itself**, why does not the following approach work?

```
ContactForm.another_field = forms.CharField(...)
```

(My first guess is that the metaclass hackery that Django uses applies only the first time the form class is constructed. If so, would there be a way to redeclare the class to overcome this?)

Comment: You're almost certainly right. This is exactly the reason you can't easily add new fields to a models.Model subclass.

Comment: With models there's the "syncdb" trouble even if the monkey patching worked. But with forms monkey patching could be a life saver at certain times IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some pertinent definitions occur in `django/forms/forms.py`. They are:

1. `class BaseForm`
2. `class Form`
3. `class DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`
4. `def get_declared_fields`

`get_declared_fields` is called from `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` and constructs a list with the field instances sorted by their creation counter. It then prepends fields from the base classes to this list and returns the result as an `OrderedDict` instance with the field name serving as the keys. `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` then sticks this value in the attribute `base_fields` and calls to `type` to construct the class. It then passes the class to the `media_property` function in `widgets.py` and attaches the return value to the `media` attribute on the new class.

`media_property` returns a property method that reconstructs the media declarations on every access. My feeling is that it wont be relevant here but I could be wrong.

At any rate, if you are not declaring a `Media` attribute (and none of the base classes do) then it only returns a fresh `Media` instance with no arguments to the constructor and I think that monkeypatching a new field on should be as simple as manually inserting the field into `base_fields`.

```
ContactForm.another_field = forms.CharField(...)
ContactForm.base_fields['another_field'] = ContactForm.another_field
```

Each form instance then gets a `deepcopy` of `base_fields` that becomes `form_instance.fields` in the `__init__` method of `BaseForm`. HTH.

Comment: +1 The point to OrderedDict lead me to SortedDict. Not sure what the differences are, but they both worked for my issue (don't know about the OP's). Thanks.