# what's the best way to modify django form at runtime?

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-forms

The code I use is:

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    other_choice1 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    other_choice2 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    other_choice3 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    other_choice4 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        exclude = ('choice', 'other_choices',)

    def __init__(self, poll_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
        choices = p.choice_set.all()
        choices_len = len(choices)
        f = ['other_choice1','other_choice2','other_choice3','other_choice4']
        for i in range(0,choices_len):
           self.fields[f[i]].label = str(choices[i])
        for i in range(choices_len,4):
           del self.fields[f[i]]
```

This is the best way I've found to modify form's fields at runtime.  It seems a bit like hacking the implementation.  What's the well-defined way to do that?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I've found the Django IRC channel has a fair number of talented devs on it - you may want to pass this page's url to them if you haven't already.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's kind of difficult to see in that code. Can you post your Poll and Vote models?

Comment: @Doc, please will you stop shilling for the IRC channel? Stackoverflow also has a fair number of talented Django devs on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `base_fields` as explained in [Monkey patching a Django form class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930512/monkey-patching-a-django-form-class/3930819#3930819) :

```
ContactForm.another_field = forms.CharField(...)
ContactForm.base_fields['another_field'] = ContactForm.another_field
```

(Or `BaseForm` as explained here http://snipt.net/danfreak/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-at-runtime-form-in-django/ :

```
def make_contact_form(user):
    fields = { 'name': forms.CharField(max_length=50),
               'email': forms.EmailField(),
               'message': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea) }
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        fields['captcha'] = CaptchaField()
    return type('ContactForm', [forms.BaseForm], { 'base_fields': fields })

)
```

Comment: How would you adapt this to a ModelForm, rather than a plain form?

Comment: Override the form's `save()` method to handle your custom fields.

Comment: However, there are probably better ways to solve your problem.  Paste your model and requirements for your form in a **new question** to get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this does seem hacky. But the reason for that is that you're thinking in the wrong direction. What you seem to want is a single checkbox for each item in a relationship, and you're trying to implement that by having one BooleanField per item. But that's not how you should be thinking at all - you should be thinking of a single field to represent the items in that relationship, and a ChecbkoxMultipleSelect widget to actually display the checkboxes.

Comment: Can you explain or give example! I don't quite follow you.